# Google Photos API - a permanent url to an uploaded item for static content

Tags: java, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm trying to refactor a Java application using the Picasa Web Albums API
to using the new Google Photos api.

In Picasa API you had the **PhotoEntry** object, which represented the uploaded entity
and one could access the URL to the uploaded image as follows:

```
photoEntry.getMediaThumbnails().get(0).getUrl();
```

This url could be used in a website as static content.

Currently I'm at a loss how to get a permanent url to an uploaded image
with Google Photos API.
There is the **MediaItem** object, which represents an uploaded image,
but I can't figure out how to get a permanent url from it.

I find 2 types of url in the MediaItem API:

```
mediaItem.getBaseUrl()
```

This url expires after 60 minutes and

```
mediaItem.getProductUrl()
```

cannot be used for static content, since it requires to be logged in.

Anybody can tell me what I overlooked ?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 2):

The Google Photos Library API is not designed for image hosting. If you'd like to embed images in another site, you may need to look at other hosting solutions, like [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) or similar.

You are correct, base URLs expire after 60 minutes and need to be refreshed. However, if you need a permanent URL to a media item that points to Google Photos, you can create a new album, share it and use the `shareableURL` that's returned as part of the [`shareInfo` property](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums#Album.ShareInfo). This URL is accessible without sign in and opens the shared album in Google Photos. You can find out more in the [share media developer guide](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/share-media).

Comment: I didn't find a way to get a permanent URL to a media item. Could you explain how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelOffengenden if by "URL to a media item" you mean a permanent URL to an embeddable JPG image, then there is no way using the API. [You can do it by hand though](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137631/23501).